# How do I replace more than one blank in c programming with one blank?

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

I am new to programming, and I have decided to start with c. I am using the book of K & R, and there is this exercise, which asks to write a program that copies input to output , replacing one or more blanks with a single blank. However when I wrote my program (and I am sure it's not correct but that's okay, since I am here to learn) I was wondering what I am doing wrong. Also a note: when I type my name with 3 blanks it's reduced to two, but when using two or one blank(s) nothing happens. Code posted below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void)
{
int c; // getchar value
int blanks = 0; // counting the amount of blanks. If more than one then  replace with blanks_2
char blanks_2 = ' '; //character value for replacement in case blanks is more than one

printf("Enter your name please\n");

while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
if(c == ' '){
    ++blanks;

    if (blanks >= 1){
        putchar(blankos);   }
    }
if(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z'){
    putchar(c);
}
if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'){
    putchar(c);
}

}

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Do you mean replace consecutive blacks with a single blank, right?

Comment: Yes. This seems not to be working @chux. I did something similar before, but this brings the blanks back to 0. When writing my name, my name is then without spaces

Comment: The answers given aren't bad, but they don't help you to understand what's wrong with your code.  If you're new to programming, learning to trace through your code is important.  So, some questions to help you find the bugs in *your* code, rather than replacing it with someone else's:  What will happen if your input is 'The...noobie.....noob' [. = space]?  Go through the loop manually for each character.  Keep track of the value of blanks, and ask yourself when you should be doing the putchar, and when you're doing it now.  What will happen to the behavior when you get between words 2 and 3?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to count the exact number of blanks. Once you find a blank "raise a flag" that blank is found. When you revisit a non-blank character print a blank and turn the flag back to 0. Moreover, insert "continue" statements in your code to avoid unecessary checks:

```
int main(void)
{
   int c; // getchar value
   int blankfound = 0;

   printf("Enter your name please\n");

   while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
      if(c == ' '){
         blankfound = 1;
         continue;
      }
      if(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z'){
         if (blankfound == 1)
         {
             putchar(' ');
             blankfound = 0;
         }
         putchar(c);
         continue;
      }
      if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'){
          if (blankfound == 1)
          {
             putchar(' ');
             blankfound = 0;
          }
          putchar(c);
          continue;
      }

 }

return 0;

}
```

Comment: okay thank you for your constructive feedback. It seems to work, i understand the first part of the loop, however could you explain me why it is necessary to add a blank everytime i visit a non -blank character?

Comment: The information that blank character(s) is/are visited is hold in blankfound variable. When the current character is a non-blank character the blankfound variable is checked for its value. If it's 1, this means that prior to the current non-blank character at least one blank character exists. So, before printing the current character value you should print a blank character as the task requires. And of course ... you should also turn the blankfound back to 0 in order to identify possible future blank characters.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to write a program that get something like this as input:

```
John        David       Doe
```

and display this as output:

```
John David Doe
```

by removing all extra spaces. This should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c; // getchar value
    int blanks = 0; // counting the amount of blanks. If more than one then  replace with blanks_2

    printf("Enter your name please\n");

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if(c == ' ')
        {
            // count blanks
            ++blanks;

            if (blanks==1)     
                putchar(c); // display only the 1st blank
        }

        if(isalpha(c))
        {
            putchar(c);
            blanks=0; // reset blanks counter as c is an alpha character
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Haven't had the isalpha function in the book yet. Just started and am on page 20. I tried to input the code though, but it does not seem to work unfortunately.

Comment: `isalpha` is not equal to `not(isspace)`, which makes me wonder why you introduced that function to noobienoob.

Answer (score 1):

Many of these learner code assignments work on the idea of function based on a *previous* character.

Consider the following layout

```
int previous = something();
while ((c =  getchar()) != EOF) {
  do_stuff(previous, c);
  previous = c;
}
```

For OP, that would be: If the character is not a space or the previous character was not a space, print it.

```
printf("Enter your name please\n");
int previous = 0;
int c;
while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
  if ((c != ' ') || (previous != ' ')) {
    putchar(' ');
  }
  previous = c;
}
```

Simplifying the algorithm helps one see flaws like below.  `blanks` is not reset when a letter appears. It prints when 1 or more spaces encountered.

```
if(c == ' '){
    ++blanks;

    if (blanks >= 1){
        putchar(blankos);   }
    }
if(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z'){
    putchar(c);
}
if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'){
    putchar(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference to previous chapters (Used only 'while' and 'if'), my code look like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == ' ') {
            putchar(c);
            while ((c = getchar()) == ' ')
                ; 
        }
        putchar(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Used `gcc -ansi` for compile